# Hbase configuration with Hdfs HA

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, namenode

I am trying to setup hbase ha with hadoop ha. I have done setting hadoop ha setup and tested it.

But in hbase setup, while starting, I am getting this following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2436)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs-nameservice
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:1003)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2419)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hdfs-nameservice
    ... 25 more
```

I think my hbase setup doesn't recognize my nameservice hdfs-nameservice.

I am using Hbase 1.2.4 & Hadoop 2.7.3.

My hbase-site.xml has

```
    <property>
            <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
            <value>hdfs://hdfs-nameservice/hbase</value>
    </property>
```

core-site.xml has

```
    <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://hdfs-nameservice:8020</value>
    </property>
```

and hdfs-site.xml has

```
    <property>
            <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
            <value>hdfs-nameservice</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.hdfs-nameservice</name>
            <value>namenode1,namenode2</value>
    </property>
    //with rpc, http address confs for both namenode1&2
```

Tried:
 1. Copied both the core and hdfs-site xmls in hbase conf directory.
 2. Added Hadoop conf path in both environmental variable and hbase-env.sh

Still couldn't figure out how to make my hbase recognize hdfs-nameservice.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Got that fixed by removing the port in defaultFS. Thanks.